# What cars are available in NFS:W?

Tags: need-for-speed-world

It is quite problematic to compare cars in NFS:W. Whenever you pick a car, you are offered the choice of the rental option, which costs money to unlock for a limited time period but comes with a large performance bonus. The performance bonus, however, is not homogeneous.

This means that one cannot compare cars by shuffling between them, as the bars always move to the rental option when browsing.

What are the cars available currently in NFS:W? How much do they cost? When do they unlock? How many performance "ticks" does each have in the *basic* version?

Comment: any car can get a NSFW car wrap if that's what you...oh wait... NFSW...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Starting cars (tier 1)

```
Car                                                          Spd Acc Hnd    k$
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Mazda MazdaSpeed 3                                           200 175 150    20
Mitsubishi Eclipse GT                                        155 180 130    20
Nissan 240SX (S13)                                           120  70  95    20
Nissan Silvia (S15)                                          160 110 135    20
Toyota Corolla                                               140  90 115    20
```

#### Level 5 unlocks (tier 1)

```
Car                                                          Spd Acc Hnd    k$
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Dodge Charger                                                150 240 130    30
Dodge Challenger                                             210 260 190    30
Wolkswagen Scirocco                                          195 220 170    30
```

#### Level 10 unlocks (tier 2)

```
Car                                                          Spd Acc Hnd    k$
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Dodge Charger SRT8 Super Bee                                 320 350 300    60
Mazda RX-7                                                   310 285 260   130
Mitsubishi Lancer Evolution IX Mr-Edition                    300 270 320    60
Nissan 350Z (Z33)                                            300 280 330    60
Volkswagen R32                                               300 250 275    60
```

#### Level 15 unlocks (tier 2)

```
Car                                                          Spd Acc Hnd    k$
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
BMW Z4 M Coupe                                               320 290 340   130
Subaru Impreza WRX STI                                       360 310 335   130
```

#### Level 20 unlocks (tier 2)

```
Car                                                          Spd Acc Hnd    k$
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Lexus IS-F                                                   330 380 355   250
Mitsubishi Lancer Evolution X                                370 320 355   250
Nissan 370Z (Z34)                                            370 340 390   250
```

#### Level 25 unlocks (tier 2)

```
Car                                                          Spd Acc Hnd    k$
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Audi S5                                                      430 405 380   400
Lotus Elise                                                  410 360 385   400
Porche Cayman S                                              395 420 370   400
Toyota Supra                                                 450 425 400   400
```

#### Level 30 unlocks (tier 3)

```
Car                                                          Spd Acc Hnd    k$
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Audi R8 FSI Quattro                                          500 550 525   600
Lamborghini Gallardo                                         450 500 475   600
Nissan GTR (R35)                                             475 500 525   600
```

#### Level 35 unlock (tier 3)

```
Car                                                          Spd Acc Hnd    k$
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Chevrolet Corvette Z06                                       575 600 550   850
```

#### Level 40 unlock (tier 3)

```
Car                                                          Spd Acc Hnd    k$
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
BMW M3 GTR (E64)                                             600 575 550 1,200
```

#### Rental only

- BMW 135i Coupe (tier 2)
- BMW M3 E92 (tier 3)
- Porche 991 Turbo (tier 3)